# creating shared pointer from a raw pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have the following struct:

```
struct Message
{
    size_t m_nBytes;
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<char> m_msg; //tr1 since I'm not using c++11

    Message(char* _message, size_t _size);
};
```

I would like to have a constructor that receives a raw pointer as a parameter so that I can use it this way:

```
Message Func()
{
    char myMsg[32] = "This is a message"; 

    Message msg (myMsg, 32);
    return msg;
}
```

What is the right way to write the constructor?
Should I use memcpy/ std::copy?

```
Message::Message(char* _message, size_t _size)
: m_nBytes(_size)
, //how to create the shared pointer? 
{
}
```

Thanks

update:
a. The message does not necessarily contains string.
b. I am trying to have a struct that will be used in a wrapper for c sockets. So I would like to have:
a. struct holding char* and size
b. dealing with memory allocation/deallocation within the struct and allowing the user the above behavior
c. being able to extract from the struct the char* and size in order to use it in read/send, write/recv functions.

Comment: You cannot create shared pointers from locally allocated memory. This sounds like a XY problem. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Can you use `shared_ptr<std::string>`?

Comment: So from what you put into your question now: You want a buffer that is auto memory managed, and can be passed around with zero copy operations? A `std::shared_ptr<std::array<unsigned char,32>` should work well. Or even a `std::unique_ptr<std::array<unsigned char,32>`

Comment: @Brian - Why not dump the pointer bit and use `std::string`?

Comment: I would consider using `std::vector<unsigned char>` for this. If you really need shared ownership then maybe `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned char>>`?

Comment: @EdHeal because the OP wants shared ownership, apparently

Comment: @Galik if I use vector, I would I extract the char* when needed? if the function write for example expects char*, can give it &charVector[0] (if (the charVector is my vecotr of chars)?

Comment: @Hana You can give your function `charVector.data()` and if it needs the size `charVector.size()`. Now you don't have to pass the size separately, the vector remembers it.

Comment: @Galik, thanks I'll try to explore this option

Comment: @Hana `unsigned char` is preferable because that's just binary. But if you need a `char*` (rather than `unsigned char*`) you can use `std::vector<char>` instead or just cast when needed `(char*)charVector.data()`.

Comment: OT tr1? Update your compiler!

Answer (score 1):

For this I would have a `const char*` consructor and *copy* the text because a local array is already owned by the *scope* and its ownership can not be transferred.

```
Message::Message(char const* _message, size_t _size)
: m_nBytes(_size)
, m_msg(new char[_size], std::default_delete<char[]>())
{
    std::copy(_message, _message + _size, m_msg.get());
}
```

If you want to take ownership of a raw pointer I would use a constructor that expresses that:

```
// tells the world you take ownership
Message::Message(std::shared_ptr<char> msg, size_t size)
: m_nBytes(size)
, m_msg(msg)
{
}
```

**NOTE:** Because you are pointing to an array you need to pass the array *deleter* (`std::default_delete<char[]>()`) to the `std::shared_ptr` constructor.

Comment: Why use `std::shared_ptr`? `std::string` will do

Comment: @EdHeal `std::string` isn't shared. I assume that's important to the `OP's` situation.

Comment: Is `std::string` immutable anyway? Seems little point to have a pointer to one

Comment: @EdHeal I can't second guess what the `OP` wants. The question is specifically about `std::shared_ptr` so... that's what I am answering.

Comment: `shared_ptr<T[]>` requires c++17, you may use `unique_ptr<T[]>` instead ...

Answer (score 0):

If the object is not going to take ownership of the memory (as your example can not), your object will have to allocate memory itself and then copy the source buffer.
At least if using a c++11 compiler you can use delegating constructors and only have to implement it just once:

```
Message::Message(char * ptr, size_t nBytes)
  : m_nBytes(nBytes), m_msg(nBytes?new char[nBytes]:nullptr)
{
  if(ptr)
  {
    assert(nBytes);
    memcpy(m_msg.get(), ptr, nBytes)
  }
}
Message::Message::Message(size_t nBytes)
  : Message(nullptr, m_nBytes)
{}
Message::Message(Message const & other)
  : Message(other.m_msg.get(), other.m_nBytes)
{}
```